# How to overlay a div on top of its parent when the parent is fixed height

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I have a `div` which has a fixed `height` and cannot be changed. (this question wouldnt exist if I could make the parent `height: 100%` )

Here is a link to the fiddle on what I am talking about - https://jsfiddle.net/s7maoekj/2/

Now how can I get the `overlay` div to perfectly overlap the `outer-container` even when the `content` div can have any content length in it?

If you check out the fiddle, ideally the blue overlay will fully encompass the content.

**EDIT 1**
Clarification since it was not fully clear

I created this to showcase my problem. I need to `visiblity: hidden` (hide) the overlay at-will and bring it back at-will

Comment: I am not completely following you. The `.overlay` div does already fully overlap the `.outer-container`. Are you asking instead for it to fully overlap the `.content` div that is *inside* the `.outer-container` div?

Comment: `.overlay` *is* extending to 100% of the height of `.outer-container` (200px). The problem is that `.outer-container`'s contents cause it to become too tall and overflow, hence the scrollbar

Comment: yes @cssyphus you are right

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the overlay around the content, and change the width and height of the overlay. Here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3rfk0u57/15/. Here's the code:

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="content">
      This is my content<br>
      ...
      This is my content<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f3;
}

.overlay {
    margin: 0 auto;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick post. I think this works, but I had not mentioned an important usecase. I need to visiblity: hidden (hide) the overlay at-will and bring it back at-will , but with this, the content gets hidden

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ef0La5/ - with visibility of overlay to be hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bit of javascript to do the magic:

```
var ctt = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
var hgt = ctt[0].clientHeight;
var oly = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
oly[0].style.height = hgt + 'px';
```

```js
var ctt = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
var hgt = ctt[0].clientHeight;
var oly = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
oly[0].style.height = hgt + 'px';
```

```css
.outer-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f3;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 9998;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
    This is my content<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Of course, it's a little easier with jQuery:*

```
var hgt = $('.content').height();
$('.overlay').height(hgt);
```

Comment: This is great. However any css only magic out there?

Comment: Pretty sure this cannot be done by CSS alone, but I never mind being proved wrong.

Comment: there is some ways with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56058755/8620333